# Authentication on NodeJS

Tags: node.js

I've watched a video on YouTube about Authentication on NodeJS. I already have a project just with get requisitions. That's the code that involves the login:

```
var sessions = require('express-session');
var session = {};
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(sessions({
    secret: 'aisdh2782782hjda82',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true
}))
```

> Methods

```
app.get('/login', function(req, res) {
    session = req.session;
    if(session.uniqueId) {
        resp.redirect('/redirects');
    }
})

app.post('/login', function(req,res) {
   session = req.session;
   if(req.body.username == 'admin' && req.body.password == 'admin'){
       session.uniqueiD = req.body.username;
   }
   resp.redirect('/redirects');
});

app.post('/logout', function(req,res) {
    req.session.destroy();
});

app.get('/redirects', function(req, res) {
   session = req.session;
   if(session.uniqueiD) {
       resp.redirect('/home');
   } else {
       end('Wrong. Try it again');
   }
});
```

> Tests

I'm testing the source with postman. For instance I've tried using post login method passing as parameter this JSON:

```
{
    "username": "admin",
    "password": "admin"
}
```

Then I got this:

```
resp is not defined
```

May someone help me? I have limited knowledge of node and I don't really know what's wrong in my code (I just copied). Obs: I'll use mysql to fetch user data.

Comment: Use `res` not `resp` in `resp.redirect('/redirects');`

Comment: Kindda worked, but even when the username or password are different it happens - > 'res.redirect('/filmes');' and not it - > 'end('Login incorreto?');'

Comment: It's because you didn't configure body-parser to parse data with json, add `app.use(bodyParser.json());` before `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));`.

Comment: I set it up when I started the project.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't yet implemented your code myself, but it comes to my eye that you pass in the parameters (req, res) and refer to the later with "resp" instead of "res". It might just be a simple typo.
Also you don't handle a correct login diffrent from an incorrect one. Implement an "else {}" case after you ceck for successful login.

Comment: Aye I just have seen that. Thank you. But are the other methods right? And why I cannot use -> else {
       end('Wrong. Try it again');
   }

Comment: I got you but there is the redirects method which is going to check the login.

Comment: You still need to send a response, so direct your user somewhere else for example use "res.redirect('/signup');" in your else case and implement a SignUp-Page.

Comment: I'll implement signup tonight. So when it is incorrect I'll send the user there. That's what you meant? But I can send them there by this 'redirects' method, right?

Comment: Also you don't need to redirect to a "/redirects" page, just redirect to "/home" directly:
`app.post('/login', function(req,res) {
   session = req.session;
   if(req.body.username == 'admin' && req.body.password == 'admin'){
       session.uniqueiD = req.body.username;
       res.redirect('/home');
   } else {
       res.redirect('/signup')
   }  
});`